# Jenkins Pipeline with no name…

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Somehow I managed to create a pipeline with no name. Looking at the log for the first build, I get:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /job//lastSuccessfulBuild/. Reason:

Not Found
```

Which is not surprising since there should be something between the `//`!

*How do I delete it?*

Here is a screen shot of the Blue Ocean interface showing the problem. Some of the names have been redacted. However, the big empty space should be visible.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried using the admin Groovy console? You could craft a Groovy script that deletes that exact `Item`. This is an isue I haven't seen before, but not surprising by Jenkins standards.

Comment: @mkobit Not knowing anything about Groovy would make that difficult. Yeah, Jenkins is awesome⸮

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating both plugins and Jenkins itself seems to have fixed this… ☹